# Multiple fonts in C++ dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, fonts, dialog, font-size

Is there a simple way in C++ (and if yes, how to do it, preferably within Visual Studio VS2012) to **set different font properties** (size, type, bold, etc) **for different elements of one dialog window** (button, static text, title, etc)?

The font properties of a dialog window can be modified in its 'properties' dialog in VS2012, but they are then applied to all the window elements.

My need is to emphasize some information wrt other in the same window, e.g. to make it visually easier to differentiate labels from variable values, and static from modifiable variables.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's no simple way to do anything in C++ when it comes to dialog boxes (or any UI control come to think of it).  In other words *you're going to have to code it* because the VS C++ designer is rubbish - I mean fantastically terrible - and VS is still using the same completely awful compiled resource system invented 30 years ago.

Comment: You seem to confirm my fears about this issue. Any simple way (links?) to achieve the goal programmatically?

Comment: For a lot of controls you'll do something like send a WM_SETFONT message to it, passing along a handle to a font object you've created some place.  If you're using MFC it might have a font property (though this is probably asking too much given it's 1982 at Microsoft).

Comment: Hmm, MSVC++ had excellent point-and-click design support for Winforms for 13 years, XAML for 3 years.  But strings are attached so it easier to complain they don't exist.  Write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a recent and well written [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/873270/Windows-dialog-design-in-Cplusplus-without-dialog), John Morrison Leon presents his solution which precisely addresses this issue and more.

On top of enabling the wished for possibilities with formatting, it offers a whole new way to easily create and use dialog windows, purely C++ (Win32 without MFC or ATL/WPL, independent of the IDE, mapping at compile instead of run time).

The piece is a rather detailed tutorial, licensed under The Code Project Open License (CPOL). It contains all C++ source code (37.2kB zip) and examples (80+kB). It has won Best C++ Article of May 2015 (First Prize).

------------- some excerpts quoted from this (long) article -----------------------

An alternative approach in which dialogs are entirely specified as C++ code that requires neither IDE support to be written nor IDE generated resources to be executed. Powered by the C++ type system.

The fundamental difference with the approach presented here is that your code does all the work of creating the dialog rather than have Windows create a dialog from a dialog template resource that you then attach code to. There is no need for dialog or control ID's because there is no run-time mapping of code to a dialog template. Instead there is compile time mapping of each control to a C++ variable. Furthermore each of those variables has its own unique data type. Such rich typing is perhaps radical but it brings many benefits and is key to the design. It allows the C++language to resolve many issues at compile time through type resolution and this reduces and simplifies the code that you have to write. In practice this means that for every variable representing a control, say btnCancel, a unique data type will be generated with the same name prefixed by an underscore _btnCancel.As you will see, there are times when you will need to refer to a control by its data type _btnCancel rather than its variable name btnCancel.

The unfamiliarity of coding a layout instead of dragging and dropping it is dealt with in the next section and after that, most things are simpler, cleaner and more concise than you are probabaly used to.

There are some other innovations including:

•all control variables carry a dynamic text dynamic text buffer as_text through which the controls window text may be read and written, and which persists when the dialog is closed.

•support for non-windows controls that are simply painted onto the dialog and respond to mouse events. (examples are provided for some cases where this makes more sense).

•support for imposing aesthetic metrics (button sizes, spacing, colours, control styles etc.) at an application level on all dialogs hosted.

•replacement of the notion of 'Anchors' with Expand_X and Expand_Y styles for controls that can benefit from being enlarged if the dialog window is enlarged.

•some modest but effective streamlining of Win 32 programming with controls.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't welcome here. You should at least present an overview of the technique.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Difficult to summarize such whole new solution. Also, gratifying my answer with -1 does for sure not entice me to try and collaborate actively again. I understand that as a newbie the system might as well bar me from further contribution.

Comment: It is a terrible way to design dialogs. 
Really terrible, thats why even motif in 1995 had graphic ui builder.